# etcd watchers through minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, etcd

Is there a good way to access the etcd datastore of a minikube cluster? I'm trying to create a watcher for events on kubernetes pods, but I need to look at the etcd changelog. So far, I have run `kubectl exec -it --namespace kube-system etcd-minikube sh`, which ssh-s me into the minikube host machine, but from there, I can't access `etcd`, `etcdctl` times out, and I can't even run `python`. Is there a clean way to do this? The links seem outdated.

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/accessing_etcd.md is outdated, as well as any other sources that reference localkube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to check minikube [v1.2.0](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.2.0) etcd v3 connection channel through [gRPC](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/dev-guide/api_grpc_gateway.md) messaging protocol and it works fine.

I've check connection in two ways: directly within `etcd-minikube` Pod and externally from my minikube hosting machine via [etcdctl](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/releases) binary injected there.

Minikube [ETCD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/) certificates inventory located here: `/var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/` and I've used some of these certs to authenticate to etcd storage.

You can use below query string for connection from within `etcd-minikube` Pod, but first you have to distribute etcd certs into this Pod; this can be done via `kubectl cp` command:

`sudo kubectl cp /var/lib/minikube/certs/etcd/ etcd-minikube:/SOME_PATH -n kube-system`

`ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --cacert=/PATH/TO/ETCD/CERTS/ca.crt --key=/PATH/TO/ETCD/CERTS/server.key --cert=/PATH/TO/ETCD/CERTS/server.crt  get  / --prefix --keys-only`

Query string from my minikube host machine accessing etcd endpoint:

`ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --cacert=/PATH/TO/ETCD/CERTS/ca.crt --key=/PATH/TO/ETCD/CERTS/server.key --cert=/PATH/TO/ETCD/CERTS/server.crt --endpoints "https://$(minikube ip):2379" get  / --prefix --keys-only`